# You are not authorized to set the license key

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, key, in-app-purchase, dashboard

I am triying to implement in app purchases in my mobile game but when I try to set the google licence key in the In-App-Purchasing panel I get this message. Have have been looking on internet and I found that the solution was to put the key into the project unity dashboard but this doesn´t work. I will apreciate if anyone can help me.

I tried reinstalling the in app purchase package, insert the key into my unity dashboard and looked everywhere in the google play console in case I am missing something but I can't find anything.[My google key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdBQb.png) [My project Unity dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS8bO.png) [The problem is still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdRfl.png)